# Spring boot embedded tomcat get resource issue

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jaxb, spring-boot

I'm in the process of migrating my project as a spring boot application (mostly for the embedded tomcat solution) from a WAR that was previously deployed on tomcat.

So I encountered a problem with the embedded tomcat container that I hope someone can perhaps offer a solution, perhaps through spring or maven instead of modifying my dependency jars that my project uses to work around this issue.

I have two data model jars that contain xsd files and each one has a catalog file in "/catalog/jaxb-catalog.xml". I found that when one of my libraries call:

```
Class loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL url = loader.getResource("/catalog/jaxb-catalog.xml");
```

It would only one xml file and ignore the second xml file as confirmed when i printed out the "url". It seems the container is "`TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader`" However, when my application is deployed in a standalone tomcat container, the "url" would include both and the container is `WebAppClassLoader`.

Comment: What do you mean by "the URL would include both"? It's impossible for a single URL to point to two different resources. If you want to load multiple resources with the same name, you should use [ClassLoader.getResources(name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources(java.lang.String))

Comment: i've set break points to have a look and indeed it does load multiple resources that have the same path, each delimited by question mark

Answer (score 1):

You can read all resources with a name using 
org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver
its a normal 'java' class so you can create an instance with new
to find all resources use 
resolver.findResources("classpath*:catalog/jaxb-catalog.xml"
have a look at the javadoc of PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver it contains some valuable information.